Why traffic_source is different for the same user_id?
I am using Google Analytics on my website, but I am experiencing behavior that, in my understanding, seems strange.
According to Google’s documentation, the traffic_source contains the origin of the user’s first access after the data has been processed. However, when analyzing the data in BigQuery, I see the same user_id associated with different traffic_source values. For example, a user accessed the site via a mobile device during Campaign X, registered, and had their user_id defined. Later, they accessed the site from a computer and logged in, which also defined their user_id. However, when I check the data in BigQuery, the computer access is shown as a direct source. Shouldn’t it still be associated with Campaign X? The report identity is already set to “Observed,” so it should use the user_id to associate information with events, correct?
After conducting hundreds of tests, I noticed that in the DebugView of my production GA, the user_id does not appear under user properties, even though it is available in BigQuery. I created a new GA from scratch, and the user_id does appear in DebugView. However, if I enable the “User-provided data collection” feature, it stops showing, and even after disabling it, it doesn’t reappear.
Could you help clarify this behavior?
